# How do I configure Cocoon to redirect mobile browsers to a mobile site?

Tags: java, mobile, apache-cocoon

I have two Cocoon sites: ABC and ABC-mobile.

If the user is coming from a mobile browser, then I want them redirected to ABC-mobile. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: i guess you should detect the user agent and redirect them. I only know how to do that in js. not java unfortunaty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect the user agent. In Cocoon the `Browser-Selector` component does exactly that (you associate browser names to user agents in your sitemap - see [documentation](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/userdocs/browser-selector.html)).

Comment: Do you have an example of what the configuration would look like?

Comment: @Mike Sickler: the documentation page contains an example with detailed explanations: see [here](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/userdocs/browser-selector.html)